# How to update a column based on a part of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to update one column records with the reference of another column in the same table for all the records in the same table using loop or any other process.

Example:

**Actual:**

```
Column1 Column2                                               
kalyan  kalyan122@gmail.com                     
arun    arun414               
mahesh  ma223ds@gmail.com                 
blog    4anyinfo
```

**Expected:**

```
 Column1 Column2                       
 kalyan122  kalyan122@gmail.com                           
 arun414    arun414                            
 ma223ds    ma223ds@gmail.com                              
 4anyinfo   4anyinfo
```

**Note:** Few records, only ID is present in the column2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL-SERVER or ORACLE?

Comment: Based on the pl/Sql and oracle-sqldeveloper tags I removed the Sql-Server tag.

Answer (score 4):

If its oracle, you can do this:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Column1 = CASE WHEN INSTR(column2, '@')
                   THEN substring(column2,0,INSTR(column2, '@')-1)
                   ELSE column2
              END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just reference the columns on your SET.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET
   Column1 = (case when INSTR(Column2,'@') > 0 then SUBSTR(Column2,1,INSTR(Column2,'@')-1) else Column2 end);
```

It will update all rows and set column1 value to the value of column2.

You can add a where clause to specify which rows you want to update.

Answer (score 1):

Try this    (assumed it as SQL SERVER)

```
  UPDATE TABLE_A SET Column1=  SUBSTRING(Column2,1,CASE CHARINDEX('@',Column2,1)-1 
  WHEN -1 THEN LEN(Column2) ELSE CHARINDEX('@',Column2,1)-1 END )
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to extract the data you want:

```
SQL> with tbl(col1, col2) as (
      select 'kalyan','kalyan122@gmail.com' from dual union
      select 'arun',  'arun414'             from dual union
      select 'mahesh','ma223ds@gmail.com'   from dual union
      select 'blog',  '4anyinfo'            from dual
    )
    select regexp_replace(col2, '^(.*)@.*$', '\1') col1_data
    from tbl;

COL1_DATA
---------------------------------------------------------------
arun414
4anyinfo
kalyan122
ma223ds

SQL>
```

So first make a backup in case:

```
create table tbl_bkup as select * from tbl;
```

Then the update statement would be:

```
Update tbl
set column1 = regexp_replace(column2, '^(.*)@.*$', '\1');
```